# Why is libao silent when loaded using dlopen?

Tags: c, audio, dlopen, dynamic-loading

I'm writing an application using [libao](https://xiph.org/ao/) for audio output.  The portion
of my program that calls into libao lives in a shared object:

```
// playao.c
// compile with: gcc -shared -o libplayao.so playao.c -lao -lm
#include <ao/ao.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void playao(void) {
    int i;
    unsigned char samps[8000];
    ao_initialize();
    ao_sample_format sf;
    sf.bits = 8;
    sf.rate = 8000;
    sf.channels = 1;
    sf.byte_format = AO_FMT_NATIVE;
    sf.matrix = "M";
    ao_device *device = ao_open_live(ao_default_driver_id(), &sf, NULL);
    if(!device) {
        puts("ao_open_live error");
        ao_shutdown();
        return;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 8000; ++i) {
        float time = (float)i / 8000;
        float freq = 440;
        float angle = time * freq * M_PI * 2;
        float value = sinf(angle);
        samps[i] = (unsigned char)(value * 127 + 127);
    }
    if(!ao_play(device, (char *)samps, 8000)) {
        puts("ao_play error");
    }
    ao_close(device);
    ao_shutdown();
}
```

If I link against this shared object in a program, it works fine:

```
// directlink.c
// compile with: gcc -o directlink directlink.c libplayao.so -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN'
void playao(void);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    playao();
    return 0;
}
```

However, if I use `dlopen`/`dlsym` to invoke it, there are no errors, but the
program does not cause any sound to be emitted:

```
// usedl.c
// compile with: gcc -o usedl usedl.c -ldl
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    void *handle = dlopen("./libplayao.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if(!handle) {
        puts("dlopen failed");
        return 1;
    }
    void *playao = dlsym(handle, "playao");
    if(!playao) {
        puts("dlsym failed");
        dlclose(handle);
        return 1;
    }
    ((void (*)(void))playao)();
    dlclose(handle);
    return 0;
}
```

However, running `usedl` with `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libao.so.4`
*does* work.  So there's something about libao that wants to be loaded when the
program starts up, and doesn't like being loaded any later.

Why is this?  Is there any way to work around this, so that libao works
correctly even if loaded later in the program's execution?

I'm running Debian 10 "buster" if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked about this on the #xiph channel on Freenode and xiphmont suggested turning [turning on verbose mode](https://xiph.org/ao/doc/config.html). Once I did that, the failing case started getting the message:

```
ERROR: Failed to load plugin /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ao/plugins-4/libalsa.so => dlopen() failed
```

So libao itself is trying to `dlopen` something, and it's failing.  It's not showing me any more details, so I ran the program under GDB and set a breakpoint on `dlopen`.  After hitting the `dlopen` breakpoint for `libalsa` and running `finish`, I tried finding what the error was by using `print (const char *)dlerror()`.  And with this, I get a more detailed error:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ao/plugins-4/libalsa.so: undefined symbol: ao_is_big_endian
```

So ao's libalsa plugin is trying to reference symbols back in libao, but it's not finding them.  Why could this be?  Referencing the `dlopen` documentation, I see:

> Zero or more of the following values may also be ORed in *flags*:
>
> **RTLD_GLOBAL**: The symbols defined by this shared object will be made available for symbol resolution of subsequently loaded shared objects.
>
> **RTLD_LOCAL**: This is the converse of **RTLD_GLOBAL**, and the default if neither flag is specified.  Symbols defined in this shared object are not made available to resolve references in subsequently loaded shared objects.

Because my `dlopen` call only used `RTLD_LAZY` and didn't include `RTLD_GLOBAL` or `RTLD_LOCAL`, it defaulted to `RTLD_LOCAL`, which does not expose the symbols in the shared object (like `ao_is_big_endian`) to subsequently loaded shared objects (like `libalsa.so`).

So, I tried changing the code from:

```c
void *handle = dlopen("./libplayao.so", RTLD_LAZY);
```

To:

```
void *handle = dlopen("./libplayao.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);
```

And lo and behold, it works!